# mysql compare floats with in clause

Tags: mysql

I have columns of type float in a table.

I have a query which takes in either one value or an array of values to compare with one of the columns and return all rows that contain that value or exist in the array of values.

WHen comparing one value, I use LIKE clause as floats in mysql cannot be compared using the equal sign.

However when comparing with the array of values, I use the IN clause, which does not work for me.

How do I compare floats using the IN clause?

Comment: Can't you CAST to a different data type for purposes of running the query?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with comparing float data isn't one of 'cannot be compared using the equal sign.' The issue is that all float values are approximations, and the = operator doesn't do approximations, only precise equality.  The same is true for the IN operator.

Most people handling float comparison use something like this:

```
 value BETWEEN target-epsilon AND target+epsilon
```

where epsilon is something like 0.0001.

Accordingly, doing

```
  value IN (target1, target2, target3)
```

is hard to make work reliably. You haven't mentioned anything about what kind of numbers you're stashing in your float values.  But, let's suppose they are latitude values,  which look something like this:  42.79842367778193. Now, obviously 42.7984237 is close enough to be considered be equal here.

So you could do this sort of thing.

```
CAST(10000.0 * latitude AS INT) IN 
     (CAST(10000.0 * 42.7984237 AS INT),  CAST(10000.0 * 43.1234567 AS INT))
```